# Is there any point to the electronics tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I noticed there is an [electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronics) tag that seems a bit redundant to me. It appears to be used on a lot of questions migrated from Physics.SE such as [Resistor on anode or cathode?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/91824/resistor-on-anode-or-cathode)  presumably because it's one of the few common one between sites, but if removed those questions would be migrated as [untagged](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) as is the case with [An amplifier with feedback](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93220/an-amplifier-with-feedback).

There are 75 questions tagged with it at the moment and most look like they could do with better tags being applied rather than it being [burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag). I wondered if there's any objections to it being removed gradually via edits and maybe an edit on the wiki for the tag to say it's deprecated?

Comment: Related meta posts: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7/should-robotics-and-electronics-tags-be-used and http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/824/blacklist-electronics-tag and http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/822/shouldnt-we-disallow-adding-deprecated-tags . I think we need to burninate and blacklist this tag

Comment: @W5VO, thanks hadn't noticed those originally. Considering one is tagged blacklist-request already and it wasn't done do you think it's worth waiting a day or two in the unlikely event someone posts a plausible objection and then me posting on Meta.SO with a few links so it gets more attention? I take it only a SE employee can actually do it unless you have some different way to request it?

Comment: I'm following up with StackExchange employees to get it blacklisted and burninated. I think this post (and the others linked) indicate clear support for that over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tag has been removed from all posts and marked as "intrinsic" - it'll still be possible to migrate posts in that use it, but it'll be silently stripped and won't be allowed on any new posts or edits.

Please help [clean up the untagged](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/untagged)

Answer (score 4):

You're correct that "electronics" is redundant, and should be avoided. Removing the tags (via a mod script, if these exist, 75 is too many to do by hand) would leave them untagged, but the untaggeds are a category which can be brought to attention, while a "properly" tagged question will get overlooked.

I'm not sure there's some incentive for working on the untaggeds, but in any case you can find them by a simple tag search, searching for "[untagged]". So, in summary, I'd prefer "untagged" over "electronics".